# mysql_fetch_assoc inside if then statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

So, I'm still new with the php coding, still learning, etc. So, if this has been asked before I'm sorry. I'm writing this off the top of my head, so any mistakes, again, sorry.

I want to pull info from the database and if it's a number then display text instead. So, I thought something like this would work (I have to check 1 - 12 with a specific word):

```
 if(mysql_fetch_assoc($result) == 1){
 echo "student";
 }else
  "generic error";
```

or since I have to do 1 - 12

```
if($row_members['ulevel'] == 1){
echo "Student";
}else
"generic error";
```

When users register, they are assigned a number as part of the insert, so there shouldn't be any error.
So I guess it's a multi-part question. How do I create a statement to check the ulvel and print it as text. 1 being a observer and 12 being the admin.

Comment: "*I'm writing this off the top of my head*"?

Comment: I was thinking of using the above listed, but asking here about it first would point me in a better direction. So, off the top of my head, meaning: this is what I'm thinking would work, but I'd rather be safe and ask than sorry and chasing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql_fetch_assoc() does not return integer value, it returns associative array of strings.

To check the status, you can simply put expression inside the if expression.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row['ulevel'] == 1){
 echo "student";
} else
  "generic error";
```

If you are checking among multiple rows

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['ulevel'] == 1){
     echo "student";
    } else
      "generic error";
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I was on the right track, I also need to change the number to display a different word. Example 1=observer 2=student up 12=admin. So would:

     `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){`
     `if($row['ulevel'] == 1){`
     `echo "observer";`
      `if($row['ulevel'] == 2){`
      `echo "student";`
      `}else`
      ` "generic error";`
     `}else`
     `"generic error";`
     `}`

or is that overkill on some level?

Comment: @BBuchanan, Better use switch for that purpose

Comment: So, example is:
    switch($query) //read the db and found said number//
    case 1:
    echo "observer";
    break;
    case 2:
    echo "student";
    break;

Comment: @BBuchanan, I am not fully sure about your plan, but may be its `switch($row['ulevel']) { }`

Comment: the plan is to read the # from the db, but give it a text name so people aren't guessing what the number means. IE 1 is observer 2 is student. So they're not seeing the numerical value as it's stored, but the text, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Thank you @Starx, using switch helped out. It was what I was looking to do:
    <?php switch($row_plevel['ulevel']){
    case 0:
    echo "error";
    break;
    case 1:
    echo "student1";
    break;
    } ?>

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {  
  if(is_int($row['ulevel'))  /* Or you can some other logic ex: 
                                $row['ulevel'] < 12 */
     print "Student";  
   else     
      print "Generic error!"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($result) == 1
```

wont work, because mysql_fetch_assoc returns an array, so you are checking to see if the array == 1, which it never will.

assuming the table contains a field called ulevel, that is of type int, and assuming you have already executed the query into a result set called $results:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
  if($row["ulevel"] == 1){
    echo "student"
  }
  else if($row["ulevel"] == 2){//do something else

  }
  .....
  else{
    echo "Generic Error";
  }
}
```

A better solution would be to store the different user types in an array:

```
$user_levels = array(1=>"Student",2=>"another".....);
```

then you could do:

```
echo $user_levels[$result["u_level"]];
```

Comment: no, I have ulevel set as varchar right now, set to be changed, one of my little bugs to work on.

Comment: Thats fine, in the array do '1'=>'' instead of 1=>''

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` fetches an associative array so comparing it with 1 wont work.
If you mean it should not be null you can us the is_null function.

If you want want check for all the elements in the array to be numeric then you can iterate over the array using a loop as in

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{    foreach ($row as $value) {
       if($value>=1 && $value<=12)
     {echo("student");

    }

    else 
    echo("Generic error");
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {    
      if(in_array(1 , $row)){
         echo 'student';
         echo '<br>';  
      }else if(in_array(12,$row)){
         echo 'Admin';
         echo '<br>';  
      }else{
         echo 'Else';
         echo '<br>';  
      }

 }
```

Comment: with this could I add multiple else if's? cause I need to change the number read from the database to a text display. So 1=observer, 2=student all the way to 12=admin

Comment: Sure. The php in_array searches a string or number in the array and return true or false.